# The correct table for vashya matching

Tags: astrology, horoscopes, kundali, vedic

What is the current table for vashya matching. Surfing around the internet I found like 5-6 different tables for vashya matching. Which one is connect ?

Comment: I did not fully get that. What is "tables for vaishya" ?

Comment: You can try match making here -- https://www.mpanchang.com/astrology/nakshatra-matching/